# Redirect homepage and specific url from old domain to new domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have a site A that needs to be migrated to site B. I have to redirect homepage of the site A to a specific page of the site B and then redirect other specific pages of site A to other pages of the site B.

What is the right rule?

es: RedirectMatch ^/$ https://www.siteb.com/

redirect 301 /example.com https://www.siteb.com/journalism/

ecc...

Thanks